# PyYAML: how to specify an include directory?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, libyaml

I build libyaml and install it into a local area:

```
yaml-0.1.5 $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/sqlminus
yaml-0.1.5 $ make install

yaml-0.1.5 $ ls -l /usr/local/sqlminus/include/yaml.h
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mh admin 54225 Jan 5 09:05 /usr/local/sqlminus/include/yaml.h
```

But when I build PyYAML, it cannot find yaml.h.

```
PyYAML-3.11 $ /usr/local/sqlminus/bin/python setup.py build

checking if libyaml is compilable
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall 
    -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/sqlminus/include/python2.7
-c build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c
-o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.o
build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:2:10:
fatal error: 'yaml.h'
      file not found
#include <yaml.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I tell PyYAML where I've installed libyaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(update)** Based on dotslash's comment below, editing setup.cfg and adding these two lines made everything work smoothly.

```
include_dirs=/usr/local/sqlminus/include
library_dirs=/usr/local/sqlminus/lib
```

**(end update)**

I think you should install dependencies.

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian based system, you could search by this

```
apt-cache search libyaml
```

Then you may find there are some packages related.

I would suggest you try to install this:  `apt-get install libyaml-dev -y`

If you are using Mac OS, you could change the source in file `check_libyaml.c`, tell it what the absolute path of *yaml.h* is.

Or just specify the path while compiling

```
python setup.py config --with-includepath=/path/to/your/install/of/python/includes/
```

Then go compiling.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858934/how-might-one-specify-or-add-a-directory-to-the-python-h-search-path-during-a-mo).

Hope this be helpful.

Comment: hmm, looks like the PyYAML setup.py doesn't have a config command.  Otherwise that would be exactly what I need!

Comment: I think you should create a file **_setup.cfg_** in that folder if it's not there. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077355/how-to-use-setup-cfg-instead-of-setup-py-with-python-2-7)

Comment: perfect, I added this to your answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on dotslash's comment, editing `setup.cfg` and adding these two lines made everything work smoothly:

```
include_dirs=/usr/local/sqlminus/include
library_dirs=/usr/local/sqlminus/lib
```